# Live Agent: Pre Chat Form Error in the Code

Tags: visualforce, liveagent

I hope you can help me with this, since i do not know where to look anymore....

I am currently working on a POC for a Live Chat Deployment and already implemented Live Chat Button, which is working fine.

Now the customer wants to have a Pre-Chat-Form, to be able to assosiate the live chat request with a possible contact in the org.

Since I am not a big developer myself, I have just copy-pasted the Pre Chat Form from the Developer Site [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_pre_chat_forms_code_sample.htm)

Unfortunately its not working and I am guessing, I have to adjust it somehow to work... ( the window which pops up tells me that the side is offline, but I am online as an agent at the moment)

Some Background Information:

We do not use Knowledge and do not have any record types for the case - but I could set up some, if needed.

Here is the Button Code:

```
<img id="liveagent_button_online_5738E0000004CQh" style="display: none; border: 0px none; cursor: pointer" onclick="liveagent.startChat('5738E0000004CQh')" src="https://fullpoc-asfinagpoc.cs87.force.com/resource/1511436894000/OnlineButton" />
<img id="liveagent_button_offline_5738E0000004CQh" style="display: none; border: 0px none; " src="https://fullpoc-asfinagpoc.cs87.force.com/resource/1511436894000/OfflineButton" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!window._laq) { window._laq = []; }
    window._laq.push(function(){liveagent.showWhenOnline('5738E0000004CQh', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_online_5738E0000004CQh'));
    liveagent.showWhenOffline('5738E0000004CQh', document.getElementById('liveagent_button_offline_5738E0000004CQh'));
    });
</script>
```

And here is the Deployment Code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la1-c2cs-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/41.0/deployment.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    liveagent.init('https://d.la1-c2cs-lon.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '5728E0000004CKF', '00D8E0000009Kqe');
</script>
```